# Format mysql query result into desired format

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my result from MYSQL query in the below format

```
Date: '2016-01-01', Resource_1: 100, Resource_2: 90, Resource_3:30, Resource_4: 20
Date: '2016-01-02', Resource_1: 0, Resource_2: 20, Resource_3:100, Resource_4: 40
Date: '2016-01-03', Resource_1: 70, Resource_2: 40, Resource_3:0, Resource_4: 50
Date: '2016-01-04', Resource_1: 10, Resource_2: 0, Resource_3:30, Resource_4: 0
```

My MYSQL result is coming in the below format:

```
2016-01-01|Resource_1|100
2016-01-01|Resource_2|90
2016-01-01|Resource_3|30
2016-01-01|Resource_4|20
2016-01-02|Resource_1|0
2016-01-02|Resource_2|20
2016-01-02|Resource_3|100
2016-01-02|Resource_4|40
2016-01-03|Resource_1|70
2016-01-03|Resource_2|40   
2016-01-03|Resource_3|0
2016-01-03|Resource_4|50
2016-01-04|Resource_1|10
2016-01-04|Resource_2|0
2016-01-04|Resource_3|30
2016-01-04|Resource_4|0
```

How do I get it into the desired format in MYSQL.

I would like to mention that my table structure is as follows:

```
DATE|RESOURCE_NAME|MARKS
```

I used the below query to get the previous query result

```
SELECT cd.cd_claim_dt AS cdt,res.res_Name AS NAME,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(cd.cd_claim_dt) = 1 AND YEAR(cd.cd_claim_dt) = 2016 THEN    
ct.ct_duration ELSE 0 END) claimed_hrs
FROM 
tbl_claim_data cd, tbl_claim_time ct, tbl_resourceinfo res
WHERE 
ct.cd_slno = cd.cd_slno AND MONTH(cd.cd_claim_dt) = 1 AND   
YEAR(cd.cd_claim_dt) = 2016 AND cd.app_SlNo = 35 AND 
cd.res_slno IN(17,22,23,24) AND res.res_SlNo = cd.res_slno
GROUP BY 
cd.res_slno, cd.cd_claim_dt, cd.cd_status
ORDER BY 
cd.cd_claim_dt
```

Comment: A simple loop in some application code will suffice

Comment: yea need help with that or if possible then format the mysql output

Comment: There are thousands of articles on processing MySQL results in PHP

Comment: if you can help me on this then it will be very useful. I know articles are there.

Comment: No doubt someone will oblige, but SO is not a code writing service. We like to see what steps/efforts you have undertaken for yourself.

Comment: This is a frequent question on this site if you want to do this in MYsql search for Mysql pivot or mysql conditional aggregation

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select group_concat(concat('date:',DATE,':',RESOURCE_NAME,':',MARKS)
 separator ' , ' )from mytable group by DATE order by DATE desc;
```

You can also use ***concat_ws()*** instandof **concat()** function